# How to keep stacktrace when filtering in grafana loki?

Tags: regex, logging, filter, grafana-loki, promtail

I am using this code part in my `promtail-config.yaml` file to filter the log lines that contains the word `INFO`.

```
    pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{env="myenv"}'
          stages:
            - json:
                expressions:
                  msg: log
            - match:
                selector: '{status="info"} !~ ".*INFO.*"'
                action: drop
            - output:
                source: msg
```

But the problem is when I use this approach to filter the logs it cause to remove the `stack trace` of `INFO` logs since the `stack trace` consists of couple of separate lines, Promtail consider it as a separate log line and that log line removed in the filtering process as that line not containing the word `INFO` in it.

How to keep the stack trace when carry on this filtering process?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using `multiline` under pipeline stages.

```
 pipeline_stages:
- multiline:
    firstline: '^\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]'
    max_wait_time: 3s
```

That makes the whole stack trace a one line and that resolves the issue.

For more details you can refer to the [grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/multiline/) about this.
Furthermore, I highly encourage everyone who has problems regarding how to properly configure the `promtail`, to refer [the grafana documentation about promtail querying.](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail)